# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" performing a three table join

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I have three tables

**Students**

```
id PK
student_name
```

**Groups**

```
id PK
group_name
student_id FK
university
```

**Subject_gkm**

```
id PK
group_id FK
lection_hours
```

When I make this query

```
SELECT groups.university, groups.group_name, students.stud_name, subject_gkm.lection_hours
                from groups inner join students
                on groups.student_id = students.id join subject_gkm
                on subject_gkm.group_id = groups.id
                order by groups.university asc;
```

using windows command line on mysql 5.5 server it works perfectly fine, but when I make this query using the following code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String database = "labdb";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";


        String select =
                "SELECT groups.university, groups.group_name, students.stud_name, subject_gkm.lection_hours" +
                        "from groups inner join students " +
                        "on groups.student_id = students.id join subject_gkm" +
                        "on subject_gkm.group_id = groups.id" +
                        "order by groups.university asc";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + database, userName, password)) {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(select);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("University: " + resultSet.getString("university")
                                + " Group name: " + resultSet.getString("group_name")
                                + " Student name: " + resultSet.getString("stud_name")
                                + " Lection hours: " + resultSet.getTime("lection_hours")
                );
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join students on groups.student_id = students.id join subject_gkmon subjec' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2820)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2769)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
    at lab4.main(lab4.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I use MAVEN as a dependency manager, my sql connector dependency is

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.32</version>
 </dependency>
```

Does any one know why this may be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1 Yelling *JDBC MYSQL ERROR WHEN PERFORMING THREE TABLE JOIN*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join students on groups.student_id = students.id join subject_gkmon subjec' at line 1
```

This tells you what is wrong, you have a syntax error. You don't put spaces between tokens like `on`.

```
    String select =
            "SELECT groups.university, groups.group_name, students.stud_name, subject_gkm.lection_hours" + // hoursfrom
                    "from groups inner join students " +
                    "on groups.student_id = students.id join subject_gkm" + // subject_gkmon
                    "on subject_gkm.group_id = groups.id" + // idorder
                    "order by groups.university asc";
```

To avoid this error, just be consistent: always include a leading or trailing space on each line.

Comment: there is a space missing before order by, too